Python `ModuleNotFoundError` inside Docker container
I am developing and testing with airflow inside a docker container. The container is created using the image ghcr.io/apache/airflow/main/ci/python3.9 from apache/airflow. Inside the container, airflow and python are installed:
$ which airflow
/usr/local/bin/airflow

$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

I tried to execute this python script inside the container
$ /bin/python3 /files/dags/play.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/files/dags/play.py", line 1, in <module>
    from airflow import DAG
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'


You are using /bin/python3 instead of /usr/local/bin/python.
This can lead to the ModuleNotFoundError.
Try this:
/usr/local/bin/python /files/dags/play.py

or
python /files/dags/play.py


This was very helpful, thanks

You are using /bin/python3 instead of /usr/local/bin/python. This can lead to the ModuleNotFoundError.
Try this:
/usr/local/bin/python /files/dags/play.py
